# Angular and ng-select. Confirmation on selected item

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-ngselect

I would like to get to work such a scenario:

1. A user selects an item in the dropdown. But previous value is still shown as selected (until a point 3 succeeded).
2. Selected value emitted through the `@Output` variable.
3. Selected value confirmed in any other place.
4. Selected value set as current in the dropdown.

As I can see, this behavior couldn't be achieved with two way binding to `[(ngModel)]` as recommended in examples.

In my particular case (using `ngrx` Store), I would like selected value (in `ng-select` dropdown) be bound to the value in the store. So the selected value will be change when appropriate `ngrx` Action changes the value in the Store.

https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select

Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution found**

Template and component's controller example. Please, read comments in the code.

**Template:**

```html
<ng-select #select (change)="onChange($event)" ... >
...
</ng-select>
```

Generally, we need a reference to the component and `change` event handler.

**Controller:**

```js
    @Component(...)
    export class NgSelectWrapper implements OnInit, OnChanges
        @Input() value: string | number;
        @Output() changed = new EventEmitter<string>();

        private _selectedValue: string | number;

        ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
            if (changes.value) {
                // Selected value can be changed only through the @Input field.
                this._selectedValue = changes.value.currentValue;
                // First time itemsList of ng-select component is not initialized,
                // so we need to wait to the next tick to select an item.
                setTimeout(() => this.selectValue(this._selectedValue), 0);
            }
        }

        onChange(event: NewDropdownOptionModel) {
            // Overwrite selection done by the user interaction and select the previous item forcibly.
            // So only ngOnChanges hook can change the selected item.
            this.selectValue(this._selectedValue);
            if (event.id !== this._selectedValue) {
                this.changed.emit(event.id);
            }
        }

        private selectValue(value: string | number): void {
            if (value) {
                if (!this.trySelectItem(value)) {
                    this.select.clearModel();
                }
            }
        }

        private trySelectItem(value: string | number): boolean {
            const item = this.select.itemsList.findItem(value);
            return item
                ? (this.select.select(item), true)
                : false;
        }
    }
```

So we do not need to use `[(ngModel)]` binding and handle a selection of an item manually.